# Openshift : pods not being deleted

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I have am using OpenShift 3, and have been trying to get Fabric8 setup.

Things havent been going to well, so I decided to remove all services and pods.

When I run

```
oc delete all -l provider=fabric8
```

The cli output claims to have deleted a lot of pods, however, they are still showing in the web console, and I can run the same command in the CLI again and get the exact same list of pods that OpenShift cli claims it deleted.

How do I actually delete these pods?
Why is this not working as designed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also delete the pod forcefully like below,it works fine

**#oc delete all -l provider=fabric8 --grace-period=0 --force**

Answer (score 10):

Deletion is graceful by default, meaning the pods are given an opportunity to terminate themselves. You can force a graceless delete with `oc delete all --grace-period=0 ...`

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Jordan's response did not work for me on openshift 3.6.

Instead I used the option `--now` equivalent to `--grace-period=1`